# How to handle event on positive button of alert dialog from another activity in android?

Tags: android

I have my common alert dialog in a common activity named say commonActivity(). In my 2nd activity myActivity(), I have a method myMethod1() and in my 3rd activity I have a method as myMethod2(), which I need to call on the click of the positive button of the alert dialog. Is it possible to use the common alert dialog in all my activities and on the click of the positive button, fire respective methods of the activities?

Comment: i dont know if its possible, and if it is, you probably shouldnt do it, what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I just want to keep a common alert dialog and use it in all activities.

Comment: create utility class and create a static method to generate alertdialog. then in any class you want to use it just call it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a Interface in commonActivity( ex: onPosClick with method onClick()) and in this Activity you should declare a variable public static  onPosClick mI;
then in your code

```
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            mI.onClick();
  }
});
```

the last in an other Activity you Impliment the Interface of commonActivity, maybe like here

```
onCreate(){
  ....
  commonActivity.mI = new onPosClick (){
      @Override
      void onClick(){
      //do something
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most elegant way to do it is by creating listener.

Example listener:

```
public interface YourListener{
    void func();
}
```

Then in your Activities you create this listener and override method func().

```
public class YourActivity implements YourListener{
    @Override
    void func(){
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity with this Dialog you register listeners and execute the method inside onClick method.

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        listener.func();
    }
});
```

Comment: thats not elegant :P you shouldnt be calling functions from other activitys

Comment: well obviously everyone should avoid using methods from other activities, but as a kind of solution to the problem it is acceptable :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this and make the method `public static`

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            YourActivity.yourMethod1();
  }
});
```

Comment: No but I need to call the common alert dialog in myActivity() and then implement its method myMethod1() in the same activity myActivity(). I hope you are getting my question.

Answer (score 0):

"I just want to keep a common alert dialog and use it in all activities. "

if this is your purpose, I think you should create a class like Utils, and create a public static method that receive the context and show the dialog

```
public static void showDialog(final Context context)
{
    try
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        ...
        dialog.show();

    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```